# perl script that would just print the tomcat version

Tags: perl, shell, tomcat

I am trying to extract just the tomcat version from the command in a perl script and ran in to issue with the regex part. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
$tomcat_ver=`sh /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/bin/version.sh`;
if($tomcat_ver=~ m/Server number: (.+)[0-9]$/s)
{
my $tomcat_version=$1;
print "$tomcat_version\n";

}
```

Comment: And what problem did you run into? What does `$tomcat_ver` contain? Not all of us have a tomcat 7.0.57 handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex would also do:

```
m/Server number: (.+)\n/)/
```

It will match till the new line character is encountered.
And to save it assign $1(predefined variable) to a custom variable where you want to store the version info.

**Edit:**

To trim spaces with the version number:

```
m/Server number:\s*(.+)\n/)/
```

Comment: This will also catch the 2nd of the 2 blanks after "Server number" and give `" 7.0.57"`. Also it doesn't work at all if the text and the number are separated by a tab instead of n blanks (which is not unlikely). [SilentMonk's pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37300571/5830574) is definitely more precise here.

Comment: @PerlDog I thought that OP want to just print version number without bothering with any spaces i.e just to find out the version. But anyway what you stated is right so ihad updated my answer

Answer (score 2):

Since the output of version.sh would be something similar to this:

```
sh /usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.57/bin/version.sh

Server version: Apache Tomcat/7.0.57
Server built:   Jul 2 2013 08:57:41
Server number:  7.0.57
OS Name:        Linux
OS Version:     2.6.32-042stab084.26
Architecture:   amd64
JVM Version:    1.7.0_21-b11
JVM Vendor:     Oracle Corporation
```

The regex to be used is

```
m/Server number:\s*([0-9.]+)/
```

"/s" means "." should match "\n" too. Since we are not using it that modifier is not necessary.